# Slanted Imageview or Shape in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-imageview, shapes

Hello i would love to implement a slanted / sloped imageview or layout in android like the one used in the Yahoo news digest App.

Here is a screenshot of what am trying to achieve

[Yahoo news digest App http://imageshack.com/a/img673/921/yDLbs2.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img673/921/yDLbs2.png)

Thanks

Comment: Could you find any solution?

Comment: @ Bhargav Jhaveri no i did not.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 things to watch care fully

1. triangle shape is fix in every layout so you have to take image of that just having that type of triangle and other side is transparent
2. thing u have to visualize that tringle area also contains the type of news like (4) US news then you have to take frame layout in which having 2 things

   1. Image (triangle shapped)
   2. TextView (or the layout that shows like (4) US News)
      and rest of the part is in linear layout.

now your confused that how that image going to place?
i also have that ans
take this example

```
    <ImageView
          src="image"
          width="fill_parent"
          height="@dimen/responsive_mesured_height"/>
    <scrollView
        fillviewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
           `orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
               width="fill_parent"
               height="@dimen/responsive_mesured_height"
               background="@android:color/transperent"/>

                   <LinearLayout>
                          <!--rest of content-->
                  </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </scrollview>
```

still if u don't believe me then go for news digest apk and download it and extract it.
after that go for mdpi-v4 folder in res folder there u find morning_triangle_background.png for light theme.
and for dark theme evening_triangle_background.png

now above code is for that image paralex effect you will feel that content are scrolling above that image just like website.
where @dimen/responsive_mesured_height is the hight of imageview (if you want to make responsive then define diff heights in all different folders like values,values-sw600dp,values-sw720dp,values-large(to support lover then 3.2) etc.

i hope this description helps all.